# Is Ethereum capable of having dynamicly typed languages?

Tags: solidity, vyper, data-types, yul, lll

I am wondering if it is at least theoretically possible for Ethereum to have a language that is loose/weak typing.
From what I've seen all the languages on Ethereum are static typed.
My understanding is that it has something to do with immutability whereby if a language is not strongly typed it will break the immutable nature of Ethereum.
Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: The EVM is Turing complete. In theory it could run any program. Perhaps it is not feasible due to the limited resources available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Solidity is a static language for security reasons, you wouldn't want your code to be flexible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Python implementation of Ethereum called Py-EVM that has support for the low level primitives for the current Ethereum 1.0 chain and emerging support for the upcoming Ethereum 2.0.

Comment: Thanks. Can you deploy python code onto that VM?

Comment: Yes, you need Web3.py